# Ionic 2: percentage height and set width does not appear in emulator

Tags: html, ios, css, angular, ionic2

I have an ion-grid element in my template called home.html, within that grid is a row with three columns:

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-col>...</ion-col>
  <ion-col width-10>
    <ion-row class="full-height j-a-center">
      <div class="vrt-line"></div>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col>...</ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

the  '...' ion-cols are displaying everything correctly in chrome and in ios emulator. However, when I emulate ios, the vrt-line div does not display anything unless I use a static height rather than a percentage, and even then, the vrt-line div does not center in the row. I use this same centering 'technique' throughout the entire app and this is the only place there are issues.

```
.full-height {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.j-a-center {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

// Works in chrome, but nothing shows up in emulator. However, all of the spacing with ion-cols are correct.
.vrt-line {
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
}

//Line appears in both emulator and chrome, but is not centered/aligned in emulator. 
.vrt-line {
  width: 2px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up playing around with the heights of every parent element to the container. Giving each element a unique background color made testing a bit easier. Ultimately, my fix was to use my 'full-height' class on each parent container to the inner-most child ion-row. I get the feeling that this is a bit of a work around. But it worked.

```
<ion-grid class="full-height">
  <ion-row class="full-height">
    <ion-col>...</ion-col>
    <ion-col width-10 class="full-height">
        <ion-row class="full-height j-a-center">
            <div class="vrt-line"></div>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>...</ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```